# Access Superset through a remote browser

Tags: remote-access, remote-server, apache-superset

I have installed  [Apache Superset](https://superset.incubator.apache.org/index.html) on a remote Linux Server and initialized it on port 8080. When I pull up localhost:8080 on the Linux server, the homepage shows up which suggests that the installation worked as per their [instructions here.](https://superset.incubator.apache.org/installation.html#superset-installation-and-initialization)

When I try to access this page from my laptop (Windows- Browser:Chrome) with http://server-name:8080. It gives me the 'This site can't be reached' page.

I tested using netcat if the connection was open by typing `nc -zvw3 server-name 8080` and it gave me `Connection to server-name 8080 port [tcp/webcache] succeeded!`

I have Jupyter installed on the same server on port 8888 and it works perfectly. Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You may need to try this command by defining the IP address:

```
superset run -h 0.0.0.0 -p 8080
```

Comment: Solve my problem! Thanks a lot! But can anyone explain it a little more?

Comment: When I run the above command I get the below error:

OSError: [Errno 98] Address already in use

Comment: @SrikanthJ Then you must be running something on that address.

Comment: Helped me quickly to allow others to access my localhost!