# Unable to publish Super set dashboard

Tags: publish, dashboard, apache-superset, gamma

I have a VM where  super set is installed able to create the dashboard and when dashboard is published
[image]

and when clicked on share dashboard getting a link as shown http://localhost:8088/r/8

but to access the published dashboard from VM named INGBTCPIC6VW108 as shown below http://ingbtcpic6vw108:8088/r/8

Getting as sown below
[image]

please help me to understand and publish the dashboard and share a link to access the dashboard from super set

Comment: found solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59147997/access-superset-through-a-remote-browser

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access Superset through a remote browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59147997/access-superset-through-a-remote-browser)

Answer (score -1):

Which type of VM do you use? It looks like you need to expose port 8088 outside of your virtual machine.